# Kernel module probe function is never called

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot, device-tree

I try to load a sample device tree driver, but the probe function is never called.

The entry in dts file looks like this

```
dummy1 {
    compatible = "ti,dummy";
    reg = <0x9f200000 0x1000>,
        <0x9f201000 0x8>;
};
```

And the relevant driver code is:

```
#define DRV_NAME  "dummy"
static const struct of_device_id dummy_of_match[] = {
{
.compatible = "ti,dummy",
}, {
},
};

static struct platform_driver dummy_driver = {
.driver = {
.name = DRV_NAME,
.of_match_table = dummy_of_match,
},
.probe   = dummy_probe,
.remove   = dummy_remove,
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, dummy_of_match);
module_platform_driver(dummy_driver);
```

I have recompiled the dtb file (dtdiff shows it contains my device) and have copied it to target, but nothing happens when I insmod the driver.
I also can't find it in /sys/firmware/devicetree/

Comment: what do you mean by copied to target ?

Comment: @yashC I run kernel on beaglebone black which is connected via serial to the host machine. The system boots using Busybox/NFS. By copying to target I mean copying recompiled am335x-boneblack.dtb to the /boot folder on the NFS.

Comment: as it is not present in `devicetree/` to start with we can assume that it has something to do with kernel not parsing it. you can try a few things. 1. Explicitly give `status=okay` 2. if this node is defined as child node of some other node check if that node is disable or so (place it under soc node if it already is not).

Comment: @yashC I did it but without slightest change. What's more - the DT successfully loads even with the dtb file removed from NFS! Could it be baked into zImage?

Comment: it is is possible that it might be the case. You can try removing the zimage file and adding new kernel image file. it should work then.

Comment: @yashC I finally got it - the problem was that uboot was silently taking the dtb file from emmc. After deleting it it started loading from NFS as required.

Comment: You can add this as answer incase someone else runs into same issue

Comment: @yashC Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to solve the issue, I even removed the dtb file...and magically the kernel continued to boot as if nothing happened. I thought dtb could be baked into zImage which is possible with some additional tweaking, but that wasn't the case.

**Solution:**
Finally, I found out that the uboot was also checking the ./boot directory on the emmc card first! Removing the dtb from there immediately made the file on the NFS 'visible'.

P.S.: If you run into similar issues try to read the outputs carefully. I began to to understand the issue when I saw the .dtb load error when I removed it on NFS, but after that a message appeared that it was successfully loaded to the memory.